# BBCode or wiki markup libraries for .NET?

Tags: .net, wiki, bbcode

What's your favourite library for .NET for handling either:

- [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) markup
- [Wiki markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_markup)

Why do you use those libraries, what is so good about them and why should I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Textile.Net](http://textilenet.codeplex.com/) will give you Textile syntax parsing, which is common in wikis.
[CodeKicker BBCode](http://bbcode.codeplex.com/) will handle BBCode parsing, as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at ["codekicker's BBode-Parser for .NET"](http://bbcode.codeplex.com/) for a solid BBCode-implementation in C#.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet package [DNA.Text](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DNA.Text/) supports bbcode and wiki markup.