# C# , Regex replace all linebreak with <br /> outside a bbcode code block

Tags: c#, regex, replace, line-breaks

I've been trying all day with no luck to regex replace the new line `"\n"` with a `"<br />"` but outside a code block like a `"**[code]**some code...**[/code]**"`.

For example if I have the following

```
string myString = "Good luck **\n** thanks [code]my **\n** name[/code]";
```

How to replace the line breaks `"\n"` with `"<br />"` outside the code tag only, using regular expression?

Comment: Can the string have multiple `[code]` blocks?

Comment: Hi, Yes it can. It's a bbcode parser that I'am building.

Comment: If you're building a whole parser... don't do it with regular expressions.

Comment: @Rawling is right - look at writing a tokenizer/parser that works as a state machine. Take a look at the source code for the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to see how it is done.

Comment: Thanks Oded & Rawling I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying and failing so many times I came up with the following code and it worked, it's vb.net BTW.

```
Public Function BBCode(ByVal strTextToReplace As String) As String
        Dim regExp As Regex
        strTextToReplace = strTextToReplace.Replace(Chr(10), "<br />")

        regExp = New Regex("\[code\]([^\]]+)\[\/code\]", RegexOptions.Singleline)
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = regExp.Matches(strTextToReplace)
        For Each m As Match In mc
            Dim gs = m.Groups()
            strTextToReplace = regExp.Replace(strTextToReplace, "<table cellpadding=""2"" cellspacing=""0"" class=""tbl_Quote""><tr><td dir=""rtl""><a class=""quote_Head"">code:</a></td></tr><tr><td><textarea class=""lined"" cols=""77"" readonly=""readonly"" rows=""1"" spellcheck=""false"">" & gs(1).Value.ToString.Replace("<br />", Chr(10)) & "</textarea></td></tr></table>", 1)
        Next
Return strTextToReplace
End Function
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This may very well fail if your BBCode is not well formed. That's why I suggested using an existing parser.

Answer (score 2):

BBCode is not a regular language, so using regular expressions to parse it is not the best approach.

Look at writing a parser based on the character stream - take a look at the source code from the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to see how this is done (basically a state machine moving from character to character).

Alternatively, use one of the existing .NET BBCode parsers, as the answers to [BBCode or wiki markup libraries for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1637704/1583) point to.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me a quick example in c# for example replacing the [b]this is bold[/b] to <b>this is bold</bold> using the HTML Agility Pack ?

Comment: @MohamedTarek - No. The HTML Agility Pack is an _HTML_ parser. I pointed you to it as an example of how to write a parser.

Comment: Forgive my bad English I'm an ESL but I meant the regex pattern to replace all \n in a string with <br/> except for the onse in [code] block.

Comment: @MohamedTarek - My answer is that regex is not appropriate (not good) for this.